# jquery dialog load on scroll

Tags: jquery, dialog, scrollto

I have the following code and want to load the dialog only once the user has scrolled past 1200px. I also am trying to get the show variable to slow down:

```
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    show: 'slide',
    hide: 'puff',
});
});
```

I am using the scrollto for another div to appear, and it is working, so looking to use the same functionality:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
    $('.backtotop').fadeIn(500);
} else {
    $('.backtotop').fadeOut();
}
});
```

Thanks for any help,
Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your initial code set `autoOpen: false`.  This will prevent the dialog from opening at initialization.  Then you can specifically call `$("#dialog").dialog("open")` using a similar scroll event as in your second piece of code.

If you want the `show` action to be slower, you can add additional options for the animation.  An example would be:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        show: {
            effect: 'slide',
            duration: 2000 // 2 second duration
        },
        hide: 'puff'
     });
});
```

Check out the [dialog api](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-show) for all available options.
There are two things you can do to have it appear once:

Destroy the dialog, or remove the event handler.

For both you can specify a function to execute when closing the dialog like so:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        show: {
            effect: 'slide',
            duration: 2000 // 2 second duration
        },
        hide: 'puff',
        close: function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog('destroy'); // this will remove the dialog
        }
     });
});
```

If, instead you would prefer to keep the dialog, then you can remove the event handler.  You would modify your scroll event like this:

```
$(window).on("scroll.singleDialog", function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1400) {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    } else {
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    }
});
```

Then in the close function remove the event like this:

```
close : function () {
    $(window).off("scroll.singleDialog");
}
```

`.singleDialog` is just an example namespace I'm using.  You can use whatever name you'd like for your specific handler.  You can look up jQuery .on() and .off() for more information.

Comment: Awesome, that works great! Thanks so much for the clarification. For everyone else, here is what I ended up using: `$(function() {
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
            effect: 'slide',
            duration: 400 // 2 second duration
        },
     hide: {
            effect: 'slide',
            duration: 400 // 2 second duration
        }
 });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1400) {
 $("#dialog").dialog("open")
    } else {
 $("#dialog").dialog("close")
    }
});`

Comment: How would I add the .one() event to this, so it only does it once (as clicking on the close button closes the dialog, but everytime I scroll it keep popping up?)

Comment: This is great, works! Is there a way to set a range, so like between 1300px and 1500px so the dialog doesn't disappear on scrolling up so quickly? And one more item, when refreshing the page from below the 1500px, the dialog pops up, but forces the window to the location of it, so like 1500 even when it was refreshed from much farther down, any ways to disable the fact that the dialog forces the window pane to scroll to where it has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() ==> 1200) {
       $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
         width: 200,
         height: 200,
         show: 'slide',
         hide: 'puff',
     });
}
});
```

Hope this help..